# Converting floats from db to be used with bcmath() OR how to use bcmath?

Tags: php, bcmath

I am getting a couple of values from a database query. The values that I am getting look like:

`10.810000000000000497` and I want to use just '10.81'.

or

`2.6899999999999999467` and I want to use just 2.69

when using `ini_set('precision', 20)`;

**How how should I use this values with bcadd() for example?** As I just want to add 10.81 + 2.69?

Comment: Use [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) or [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to acomplish what you want.

Comment: The problem I am facing involves multiple variables what I am getting from the database. This variables get added, subtracted, multiplied etc. In most of the cases it works fine, but in some cases somehow the error propagates and I am NOT receiving the expected results (usually one cent missing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **php BC_** functions has another option: **scale**.

```
$num1 = 10.810000000000000497;
$num2 = 2.6899999999999999467;
$result = bcadd($num1, $num2, 2);
echo $result; // 13.50
```

If you want to use it several times you may use [bcscale()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcscale.php) and such you won't need to specify the third option each time you use it:

```
bcscale(2);
$num1 = 10.810000000000000497;
$num2 = 2.6899999999999999467;
$result = bcadd($num1, $num2);
echo $result; // 13.50
```